# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager inside of ViewPager2

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, android-viewpager2

I found a bug when using ViewPager2 (horizontal orientation), which the fragment contains a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (vertical orientation),

The RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager always jump-scrolls to top (1st item) when I scroll it vertically,

this issue does not exist when I change it to LinearLayoutManager

I suspect that this has something to do with bubbling onTouch event from nested recycler view, (AFAIK viewpager2 use RecyclerView)

Need help

---

Update: after doing research, it is may be caused by SwipeRefreshLayout wrapping my RecycleView, seems I need to extend it to something like "NestedScroll Swipe Refresh Layout"